# Why can't I get the increased counter value?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to do a global counter using monads in Haskell, I want to get the incremented value every time I use the monad counter, but I am kind of stuck getting the same value each time! 
The code list is  as follows:

```
module CounterMonad where

data Counter a = C (Int -> (Int, a))

--reset the counter
new :: Counter ()
new = C $ \_ -> (0, ())

-- increment the counter:
--inc :: Counter Int
--inc = C $ \n -> (n+1, n)
inc = get >>= \s -> (put (s+1))

-- returning the current value of the counter
get :: Counter Int
get = C $ \n -> (n, n)

--
put x = C $ \n -> (x, x)

--return is nop, >>= is sequential exectuion
instance Monad Counter where
    return r = C $ \n -> (n, r)
    (>>=) (C f) g = C $ \n0 -> let (n1, r1) = f n0
                                   C g' = g r1
                               in g' n1

run :: Counter a -> a
run (C f) = snd (f 0)


tickC  = do
  inc
  c <- get
  return c
```

When I try to execute as `run tickC`, it always returns 1.
What I want is everytime I `run tickC`, it returns the incremented value, like 1, ,2, 3,4 ....
I know there must be some stupid problem lying there, can you guys point out how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct behavior.  Every time you call `run tickC`, the `run` function evaluates the operation with the counter set to zero.  Essentially, each time you call `run` you get a different "copy" of the counter initialized to zero.

If you want to have the counter increment each time, you have to execute all operations in the same call to `run`.  For example,

```
tickMany = do
    x <- tickC
    y <- tickC
    z <- tickC
    return [x, y, z]

> run tickMany
[1, 2, 3]
```

This is true of all monads, including `IO` (ignoring the "unsafe" operations).  Since the only way to run an `IO` operation is through `main`, the `IO` monad is threaded through every function that uses it.

So if you want a global counter, that counter has to be managed by a monad that is used globally (i.e., by every function that needs to access it).  You can either use your `Counter` monad globally or put the counter in the `IO` monad.  It seems to be accepted design practice to put state like this in your own monad, but of course, it depends on the application and `IO` is fine too.

You may also wish to look at `Control.Monad.State`, which would allow you to define your monad with much less typing.  Something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
import Control.Monad.State
newtype Counter a = Counter (State Int a) deriving (Monad)
...
```

Comment: Thanks Dietrich~~ But I am not quite understanding how to do:  So if you want a global counter, that counter has to be managed by a monad that is used globally (i.e., by every function that needs to access it). You can either use your Counter monad globally...

Comment: So if you want any function to use the counter, it has to be in the `Counter` monad.  Then, any function which uses that function also has to be in the `Counter` monad, and so on.

Comment: Put Monadic transformers onto your list of things to learn to undrstand how to manage multiple monads at once.

Comment: @freezdom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302249/how-to-implement-a-global-counter-using-monad/6349651#6349651